# How to find out which section the static table view cell belongs to?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a static table view with different sections. Here you can see one of the sections:

[image]

Users can tap the cells in these sections to check them, but I want them not to be able to tap two cells from the same section, for example, if they have tapped the cell named "Name A-Z", then they tap the one named "Name Z-A", the first one gets unchecked, and the second one gets checked. To do so, I think, I should somehow check whether two cells are from the same section or not, but I don't know how to implement that. I'm using

```
tableView(_ didSelectRowAt:)
```

method for selecting the cells, but I don't know how to access cells' sections from there. Maybe I should use another method? Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: These are static cells yes? You could use tags and disable the other two cells when one is selected. If you would like I can provide an answer showing how to do that.

Comment: You could use a selectedIndex variable in the view controller for that section and if it changes you reload the section.

Comment: @CaseyWest That would be nice. Thanks

Comment: @lufritz what do you mean by saying "a selectedIndex variable in the view controller for that section"? I should create a variable to track to which section the cell belongs, or what? Could you explain that part?

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions about my answer. @TigranIskandaryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the code below lets you do a specific action whenever a cell is selected. The code recognizes what section it is in automatically as well.

Currently the table updates the label to say selected and automatically sets the other two to N/A. You can replace this with your own code to hide/show a checkmark or something.

[Here is a video](https://vimeo.com/240722510) of what the following code does as well.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            sectionOneCellOne.textLabel?.text = "SELECTED"
            sectionOneCellTwo.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
            sectionOneCellThree.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
        case 1:
            sectionOneCellOne.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
            sectionOneCellTwo.textLabel?.text = "SELECTED"
            sectionOneCellThree.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
        case 2:
            sectionOneCellOne.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
            sectionOneCellTwo.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
            sectionOneCellThree.textLabel?.text = "SELECTED"

        default:
            break
        }
    case 1:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            sectionTwoCellOne.textLabel?.text = "SELECTED"
            sectionTwoCellTwo.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
            sectionTwoCellThree.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
        case 1:
            sectionTwoCellOne.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
            sectionTwoCellTwo.textLabel?.text = "SELECTED"
            sectionTwoCellThree.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
        case 2:
            sectionTwoCellOne.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
            sectionTwoCellTwo.textLabel?.text = "N/A"
            sectionTwoCellThree.textLabel?.text = "SELECTED"
        default:
            break
    }
    default:
        break
}
```

}

The `sectionOneCellOne` variables and such are just individual cells defined in the View Controller.

Comment: My implementation is a little bit different (I add a checkmark and change the cells' isSelected property), but the approach is the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` you can get the section using `indexPath.section`. Store the indexPaths of selections in an array and check for and replace the indexPath with the same section when one is encountered inside `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Like this:

```
var selectedIndexPaths:[IndexPath] = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
   if let sameSectionPathIndex = selectedIndexPaths.index(where:{$0.section == indexPath.section}){
      if let previousSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at:selectedIndexPaths[sameSectionPathIndex]){
         //Do unchecking and anything else with the previously selected cell
      }
      selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: sameSectionPathIndex)
      selectedIndexPaths.insert(indexPath, at: sameSectionPathIndex)
   } else {
      selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
   }
   if let toBeSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
      // Do checking and anything else you want with the newly selected cell
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do exactly what lufritz said.

Create a variable in your viewController to have your selected index

```
var selectedIndex = -1
```

you can set the value with -1, because 0 is the first cell of the table.

i dont know how you want to make the select effect, in this example i just change the background color, created two functions for select and deselect the cells:

```
func selectCell(cell:UITableViewCell){
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
}

func deselectCell(cell:UITableViewCell){
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

After that in your `cellForRowAt indexPath:` method you can do something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell"){
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Example \(indexPath.row)"

        deselectCell(cell: cell)

        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row{
            selectCell(cell: cell)
        }

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell.init()

}
```

if the `selectedIndex` is the current `indexPath.row` you use the selectCell method, but first you have to use the deselect method, for deselect the last one.

the last thing is set the `selectedIndex` variable, like you thought, put it in `didSelectRowAt indexPath` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```